# How do I beat 'Journey of the Prairie King' in multiplayer?

Tags: stardew-valley

I would like to beat the arcade game in multiplayer. I am not the host.

The issue here is that a standard playthrough in the arcade game takes longer than an unpaused Stardew Valley day. Is it possible to complete Journey of the Prairie King in a multiplayer world? Is there some way to pause the game or otherwise make the day last longer so as to grant me enough time to do it?

Comment: Let me know whether me anwer is good enough for a green checkmark or if it leaves anything open that I haven't covered yet.

Answer (score 2):

### As of [1.5](https://stardewcommunitywiki.com/Version_History#1.5), you can finish the game in multiplayer.

Finishing "Journey of the Prairie King" is now possible in multiplayer due to the option to save your progress and resume the game at a later time. So you may complete it in multiple sessions.

Whereas before 1.5 you could not finish it because one maximum-length game-day (20 hours) passes in real-time in 14 minutes 20 seconds and a complete run takes about 20 minutes if played optimally.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't (in vanilla games at least). Host can pause the game, but from what I know it also pauses the arcade game itself, unlike most menu (I havent tested as a host, but for farmhands this is the case).

Comment: This answer is outdated, I provided a correct answer.